# Storm worker died after running for 2 hours

Tags: apache-storm

I write a topology to read topic from kKafka and then do some aggregation and then store the result in database. The topology was running fine for several hours, but then the worker died and eventually the supervisor died as well. This issue occurs every time after running for several hours.

I'm running storm 0.9.5 on 3 nodes (1 for nimbus, 2 for workers).

This the the error I got in one of the worker's log:

```
2015-08-12T04:10:38.395+0000 b.s.m.n.Client [ERROR] connection attempt 101 to Netty-Client-/10.28.18.213:6700 failed: java.lang.RuntimeException: Returned channel was actually not established
2015-08-12T04:10:38.395+0000 b.s.m.n.Client [INFO] closing Netty Client Netty-Client-/10.28.18.213:6700
2015-08-12T04:10:38.395+0000 b.s.m.n.Client [INFO] waiting up to 600000 ms to send 0 pending messages to Netty-Client-/10.28.18.213:6700
2015-08-12T04:10:38.404+0000 STDIO [ERROR] Aug 12, 2015 4:10:38 AM org.apache.storm.guava.util.concurrent.ExecutionList executeListener
SEVERE: RuntimeException while executing runnable org.apache.storm.guava.util.concurrent.Futures$4@632ef20f with executor org.apache.storm.guava.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$SameThreadExecutorService@1f15e9a8
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to connect to Netty-Client-/10.28.18.213:6700
        at backtype.storm.messaging.netty.Client.connect(Client.java:308)
        at backtype.storm.messaging.netty.Client.access$1100(Client.java:78)
        at backtype.storm.messaging.netty.Client$2.reconnectAgain(Client.java:297)
        at backtype.storm.messaging.netty.Client$2.onSuccess(Client.java:283)
        at backtype.storm.messaging.netty.Client$2.onSuccess(Client.java:275)
        at org.apache.storm.guava.util.concurrent.Futures$4.run(Futures.java:1181)
        at org.apache.storm.guava.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(MoreExecutors.java:297)
        at org.apache.storm.guava.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.executeListener(ExecutionList.java:156)
        at org.apache.storm.guava.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.execute(ExecutionList.java:145)
        at org.apache.storm.guava.util.concurrent.ListenableFutureTask.done(ListenableFutureTask.java:91)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:380)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.set(FutureTask.java:229)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:270)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Giving up to connect to Netty-Client-/10.28.18.213:6700 after 102 failed attempts
        at backtype.storm.messaging.netty.Client.connect(Client.java:303)
        ... 19 more
```

And this is my configuration for each worker node:

```
storm.zookeeper.servers:
- "10.28.19.230"
- "10.28.19.224"
- "10.28.19.223"
storm.zookeeper.port: 2181
nimbus.host: "10.28.18.211"
storm.local.dir: "/mnt/storm/storm-data"
storm.local.hostname: "10.28.18.213"
storm.messaging.transport: backtype.storm.messaging.netty.Context
storm.messaging.netty.server_worker_threads: 1
storm.messaging.netty.client_worker_threads: 1
storm.messaging.netty.buffer_size: 5242880
storm.messaging.netty.max_retries: 300
storm.messaging.netty.max_wait_ms: 4000
storm.messaging.netty.min_wait_ms: 100
supervisor.slots.ports:
- 6700

supervisor.childopts: -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=12346
#worker.childopts: " -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1%ID%"
#supervisor.childopts: " -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=12346"
worker.childopts: -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=2%ID% -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -Xmx10240m -Xms10240m -XX:MaxNewSize=6144m
```

Comment: I am currently getting an error very similar to this `2015-08-06 16:20:56 b.s.m.n.Client [INFO] failed to send requests to <host name removed>/<ip address removed>:6700`. So far all I've learned is that netty is used for inter-worker communication within storm and I think this error occurs when there is high load on the topology... If I find out more information I'll let you know.

Comment: Hi, please see my answer below to see if it can help you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think I found the root cause base on this thread: https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/storm-user/201402.mbox/%3C20140214170209.GC55319@animetrics.com%3E

The netty client error are only symptoms, but "the root cause was that GC logging for workers had been turned on without
specifying an output file. As a result the GC logging went to standard output without being redirected to logback. Eventually the buffer filled and the JVM would hang (and thus stop heartbeating) and be killed. The amount of time the worker would last depended on memory pressure and allocated heap size (obviously, in hindsight   the more GC, the more GC logging, the faster the buffer fills)."

Hope this can help you guys.

Comment: Thanks for updating your question with the answer so if anyone else runs into this problem they know what went wrong.